# Is it possible to write jquery.validate error codes into localstorage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am not sure if this is even possible. So I am presenting this to any professionals with knowledge in this area. Is it possible to write the jquery.validation error codes into localstorage? I am using jquery.validation for much of my site. If a user inputs an incorrect email, the error "please put in a valid email" pops-up. If the user refreshes the page the incorrect email still remains but the pop-up error no longer exists. Are there any professionals that know if this is possible, and if so how can I do this?

I have successfully got the validation code to work on all my forms. However I am not comfortable manipulating the script's source code without proper knowledge.

```
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#email_preference").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            my_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist 
                of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at 
                least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at 
                least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same 
                password as above"
            },
            my_email: "Please enter a<br>valid 
            email address",

            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at 
                least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same 
                password as above"
            },
            agree: "Please accept our policy",
            topic: "Please select at least 2 topics"
        }
    });
```

I have attached the options code from my page. The script's source code is too long to paste here. However, this is the link to the script.
https://jqueryvalidation.org/
If possible I would like the error code from an incorrect email to be written into localstorage as soon as the popup error appears on the page, so it will appear after a possible page refresh. If the email is corrected I would like for the localstorage entry to be removed. To the few that know how to do this, I thank you ahead of time.

Comment: I suggest you go back to the jQuery Validate website and review the documentation.  There are several methods/option where you have access to the error messages and then can overwrite with your own functions upon initialization.  There should never be a need to rewrite or edit the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of jquery.validate (Brahim Arkni.) suggested I use the highlight function in order to set the localstorage item as the error is triggered. The nice thing about using highlight is that you can trigger the removal of the localstorage item with unhighlight. So the code to do this part (supplied by Brahim) is as given.

```
//'''
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // Check for your email input
            if (element.type === "email" && element.name === "input_name") {
            // `errorMap` is an internal Key/value store, where the key refers to the
            // name of an input field, values the message to be displayed for that
            // input.
            localStorage.setItem("email_error", this.errorMap[element.name]);
            }

            // Call the default highlight to keep the original behaviour
            $.validator.defaults.highlight(element, errorClass, validClass);
        },
          unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            // Check for your email input
            if (element.type === "email" && element.name === "input_name") {
              localStorage.removeItem("email_error");
            }
```

Now in order to call the code on a page refresh or a browser crash you can use this code.

```
    // Show the error at startup if it was already set
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("email_error")) {
        $("div_holding_input").after('<span id="id_given_by_jquery.validate-error" class="error">Please enter a<br>valid email address</span>');
    };
    $('#input_id').click(function() {            
        $("#id_given_by_jquery.validate-error").remove();
        localStorage.removeItem("email_error");
    });
```

You are inputting the entire span that is produced by jquery.validate to show on page refresh. You will need to delete the entire span and the localstorage once the user starts typing again because jquery.validate will initialize and add a second error to the page. I am not an expert but I did work on this to get it to function properly. If anyone can make the code better I would definitely love to learn. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I guess the original author would have the best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to store to localStorage.

**Will not work in SO, you need to try the below in your environment.**

```js
let codes = {
  rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    username: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    }
    agree: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
    password: {
      required: "Please provide a password",
      minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long "
    }
  }
};

localStorage.setItem('your_codes', JSON.stringify(codes));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('your_codes')));
```

Comment: Hello Nidhin, I see the values in localstorage, but unfortunately it broke jquery.validate altogether. Nothing validates now.

Comment: can you explain more? we did not change any values.

Comment: Hello Nidhin, I copy and pasted your code in and the errors no longer display. Above your code I have the doc.ready and $().validate({ functions. I attempted to put your code inside and outside the doc.ready function. It does not function either way.

Comment: @kejo there might be something you are missing. Check this fiddle mate https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/20xqnh31/

Comment: Hello Nidhin, I think you only have the optional codes. These won't initiate the validation alone. Do you know how to add the validation initiation along with the functioning localstorage?

Comment: so, what exactly are you trying to store to localStorage?

Comment: I would like to store all of jquery.validation items. So when an error pops-up that triggers the save to localstorage for that item. When the error message goes away I would like the removeItem to be triggered to remove that same localstorage item. Right now I am focusing on the email validation because I am unable figure them all out at the same time...unfortunately.

Comment: Nidhin, you're just saving the initialization options without actually initializing the plugin method.   I believe the OP is asking about how to save the validation messages dynamically as the form is being validated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the docs and look at [the `showErrors` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).  This function includes an `errorMap` and `errorList` that you could write into local storage.

```
$("#email_preference").validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    messages: {
        ....
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // insert your function here to write the errorMap and errorList into local storage
        // errorMap = Key/value pairs, where the key refers to the name of an input field, values the message to be displayed for that input.
        // errorList =  An array for all currently validated elements. Contains objects with the following two properties: message and element

        localStorage.setItem('Error_Map', JSON.stringify(errorMap));
        localStorage.setItem('Error_List', JSON.stringify(errorList));

        // the following line inserts the default inline error messages back into the form.
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/4o50mLty/](https://jsfiddle.net/4o50mLty/)

**EDIT**:  You could use the `submitHandler` or `success` callback for a similar function that clears out the local storage when the form and/or elements are valid.  However, if you inspect the console on the demo above, you will see that local storage is automatically being cleared out as the form fields are validated.

Again, take a look at all the [available options in the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: Hello Sparky, thanks for the help. This answer still does not load the error on a page refresh. I am looking for a solution that stores the  error into localstorage and loads the error if the page is refreshed if the error still exists. The removeItem happens after the email/error is corrected. Thx

Comment: @kejo - now this is getting ridiculous.   It’s Javascript; client-side validation. A page refresh is going to reset everything just as if it’s a new visitor.   Tens of thousands of people use this plugin without the need for a local storage scheme.  You might want to take a step back and re-examine what you’re trying to accomplish.   Maybe consider some kind of server-side code to track the session and do data storage.

Comment: Hello Sparky, Please read the original question. I am not sure why you would think I would want to store things to localstorage for no reason. The only reason the localstorage is being used is to save items to be used later.There are many form items here and everything works great when the page is refreshed or the browser accidentally closes or crashes. Of course we have all seen this happen...have you seen firefox "aww snap!" popup? In any regard, for user experience all the form items here do reload as needed but the missing part are the errors that were present prior to page crash/refresh.

Comment: @kejo, yeah, I read it, and never said you wanted to do it for no reason.  But nobody does that (not with Javascript).  Nobody.  You might be the first.  Again, might have better luck using server-side technology like sessions and saving things to the server.  Anyway, I've shown you how to get the error messages and which callback functions give you access to them.  If it's not perfect, then make it better; I've certainly pointed you in the direction.